# Tablayout is covering the viewpager inside the CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:elevation="2dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/tab_layout_bg"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_indicator_color"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Is the only solution to add a padding to the viewpager?

Comment: Is your tablayout at the top or the bottom of the screen? Maybe try and add it above the viewpager in the xml. That's the only difference I can spot from my project, and mine works :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to implement the layout_behavior.

In the Viewpager attributes, add

```html
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

That is what scales the viewpager height depending on the appbar location.

You may also want to take a look at [Cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/include_list_viewpager.xml), which shows a properly impelemented setup and example of nested scrolling.